# Real average on all values of a dataframe using rolling with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

If I have a df like this:

```
    a001         a002           
      1            1             
    NaN            7             
    NaN          NaN          
    NaN            3             
    NaN          NaN         
    2              2           
    NaN            6
```

And if I want to make the calculation of the mean on window of 2 rows, I can use this:

```
df['rolling_mean'] = df.mean(axis=1).rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
```

which returns:

```
    a001  a002  rolling_mean
0   1.0   1.0           1.0
1   NaN   7.0           4.0
2   NaN   NaN           7.0
3   NaN   3.0           3.0
4   NaN   NaN           3.0
5   2.0   2.0           2.0
6   NaN   6.0           4.0
```

That is an average on a window of 2 rows, using the average of the elements of the single rows. So for example the `rolling_mean` in row1 (4) is an average between the average of the row0 `(1+1)/2 = 1` and the value of row1 (7): `(1+7)/2 = 4`

If I want instead an average of these 3 values in the first 2 rows I should have as result: `(1+1+7)/3 = 3`.
To obtain it I've used this:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df['sum'] = df2.sum(axis=1).rolling(window=1, min_periods=1).mean()
df['count'] = df2.count(axis=1).rolling(window=1, min_periods=1).mean()
df['last_2'] = df['sum'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).sum() / df['count'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).sum()
```

That returns my desired output:

```
   a001  a002  sum  count     last_2
0   1.0   1.0  2.0    2.0   1.000000
1   NaN   7.0  7.0    1.0   3.000000
2   NaN   NaN  NaN    0.0   7.000000
3   NaN   3.0  3.0    1.0   3.000000
4   NaN   NaN  NaN    0.0   3.000000
5   2.0   2.0  4.0    2.0   2.000000
6   NaN   6.0  6.0    1.0   3.333333
```

My question is: is there a more elegant and pythonic way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working:

```
df['last_2'] = (df.sum(axis=1).rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).sum() / 
                df.count(axis=1).rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).sum())
print (df)

   a001  a002    last_2
0   1.0   1.0  1.000000
1   NaN   7.0  3.000000
2   NaN   NaN  7.000000
3   NaN   3.0  3.000000
4   NaN   NaN  3.000000
5   2.0   2.0  2.000000
6   NaN   6.0  3.333333
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Joe - Glad can help!